# how to get muliplte checked datagrid checkbox items with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox, datagrid

I have datagrid which consist of  muliple data grid checkboxes,i want to get the datagrid checked items,i am able to get only the single selected row item,but i need collection of checked checkboxes, below code i am using .Please let me know how to resolve this

****Xaml*******

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ManualDataTable}"   Background="{Binding ElementName=gd,Path=Background}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding UserID}" Width="60" />
<DataGridTextColumn   Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="140" Header="Name"  FontSize="16" FontFamily="segoe_uilight" IsReadOnly="True" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
             </DataGrid>

<Button BorderBrush="{x:Null}"   Content="Add participants"  Width="220" Height="50"  FontSize="20" Command="{Binding SaveAssignedUser}"/>
```

*******View Model*************

```
DataTable _manualDataTable;
        public DataTable ManualDataTable
        {
            get
            {
                return _manualDataTable;
            }
            set
            {
                _manualDataTable = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ManualDataTable");
            }
        }
       private List<DataRowView> selectedRow;
       public List<DataRowView> SelectedRow
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedRow;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedRow = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedRow);
            }
        }


 public void ExecuteSaveAssignedUser()
 {
 SelectedRow = new List<DataRowView>();**///need multiple checked checkboxes collection**
foreach (DataRowView drv in SelectedRow)
 {
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your DataGridCheckBoxColumn is bound to a `UserID` property, which I assume is a column in your DataTable. This column value *should* get updated with true/false as you check and uncheck the boxes. In your `ExecuteSaveAssignedUser()` method you should be able to iterate through the rows in your DataTable and examine the value of UserID to determine whether it has been checked in that row.

Comment: @AndrewStephens exactly what i need is the datagrid items .but how can i get the datagrid items here?can you provide a sample of code lines will be helpfull.Also in selected row it gives only one item i need colection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox column is bound to a a property called `UserID`, which I guess is the name of a column in your DataTable. Whenever you check/uncheck a checkbox in the datagrid, the binding will change the value of `UserID` to true or false, in the relevant DataRow of the DataTable.

*Why would you bind a checkbox column to a user ID? I suspect this isn't what you actually want. Instead you probably need to add a boolean column to your DataTable (e.g. `IsSelected`), and bind your checkbox column to that instead*.

It looks like you are using MVVM, so it isn't possible to access the datagrid items from within your view-model. You can only access the data that the grid is bound to (i.e. your DataTable). Your view-model code needs to iterate through the rows in this DataTable, examining the value of the UserID column (or the "IsSelected" column if you add one!) to determine whether that row's checkbox is checked in the datagrid.

The `SelectedItem` property that you are binding to is completely unrelated to your checkbox column. Checking and unchecking these will have no effect on `SelectedItem`. This property is used to determine which row the user has selected with the mouse (which gives the row a different b/g colour). Forget about this property - it's not relevant to what you are trying to do.

As already mentioned elsewhere, try and avoid DataTables in WPF. Instead, define some kind of "User" class, and have your view-model expose a collection of these for your grid to bind to.

Comment: actually i am beginner in MVVM thats why i know this way i bind userid directly without making any template in which i take the checkbox control and use ISelected as you suggested but as i am growing in knowladge will use proper ways.thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the entire point of data binding... that is that *you* have access to all of the data that is displayed in your `DataGrid` from your code behind. You have bound the `ManualDataTable DataTable` property to the `DataGrid`, so the values that are data bound to the `RadioButton` controls are all in one column of your `DataTable`.

Therefore, all you need to do to access them is to look in your `DataTable`. There are several ways to achieve this, but here is one:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ManualDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row[requiredColumnIndex] == true) AddRowToSomeCollection(row);
}
```

However, if you're going to continue to use WPF, I'd seriously advise that you stop using these old classes, such as `DataTable`s. Generally in WPF, we define custom classes and that makes everything much simpler in the long run.

Comment: actually intially i was using observablecollection but then i tried this way i.e using datatable property.Please suggest any link or code from where i can improve this.